# Using Backbone or similar framework with Silverstripe

Tags: backbone.js, javascript-framework, silverstripe

I am replicating an existing application in Silverstripe (PHP framework). The application has a lot of jQuery already and while its organised well at the moment it could get out of control as I grow it past its current point.

Having spent most of my development experience in PHP/MySQL, I have little experience in js front-end frameworks and would not likely use a framework to manage data manipulation with the server from the get go. Really I'm just looking for a suitable solution to organise and manage the js in the short term and something I can eventually evolve (with more experience under my belt) to a point I can manage all frontend logic with.

Is backbone the way to go? Any other advice?

Comment: when you say `while its organised well at the moment` can you give some code of how you get data from the server and how you render it to your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using SilverStripe framework with [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/) and [EmberData](https://github.com/emberjs/data) with great success. Ember connects to SilverStripe with a [RESTful API module](https://github.com/colymba/silverstripe-restfulapi)

But you can very well use any JS framework and mkae your own SS controller of find other SS modules to help http://addons.silverstripe.org/

Comment: Thanks, Ember looks great. I think I will go with backbone for now as it seems less strict in how I do things which is ideal for me right now. By the way, great work on the SS RESTful API modeul, quick question on the module, how do I lock down what attributes I want available on a model. e.g. For member class I don't want to show password and encryption type?

Comment: You can define `onBeforeSerialize()` function on your model or a dataextension. Then you can remove/add properties to the model like `$this->password = null` or `$this->owner->password = null`